# Find one side of the triangle given other two sides and one angle

Tags: geometry

I couldn't come up to the answer of this question.

There is a triangle with side length AB = 85, BC = 143 and angle of A = 50 degree. I need to find third side.

Some hints or which formula I can use would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use first the law of sines and then the law of cosines. I hope that is enough information for you, if there are any problems just ask for another hint.
Greetings,

Intergalakti

Comment: I came up with idea to use cosine law, however I cannot find expression of sin50 or cos50, and it is not allowed to use calculator.

Comment: You'll hardly find it, since sin50=cos40 and cos50=sin40 are irrational and, moreover, awkward and not handy. For instance, cos 40 is one of a roots of  the following cubic equation: $cos(120)=4cos^3(40)-cos(40)$,   $8x^3-6x+1=0, cos40=x$. If use sine law, then $AC=\sqrt(143^2-80^2sin^250)+80cos50\approx180.62$

Answer (score 0):

$$BC^2=AB^2+AC^2-2AB\cdot AC \cos(A)$$
You already know BC,AB and angle of A so you can find AC

Comment: I do not know exact value of cos50, and I cannot use calculator for that:(

Comment: @curiosityy: You can't possibly solve this without knowing $\cos 50^\circ$, I'm afraid.